# ACF Как запретить вывод acf-comment-fields?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

На WordPress сайте используется [ACF плагин](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) в котором добавлена возможность для пользователя назначать изображение Аватара при помощи данного плагина из админки.
[image: Назначение аватарки из админки пользователя]

Но почему-то теперь в добавлении комментариев на странице поста начинают выводиться все данные этих полей, хотя они там и не запрашиваются мною. * вывод полей производиться дефолтной функцией

```
<?php if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) :
                    comments_template();
endif; ?>
```

[image: ACF паразитные блоки]

Вопрос - каким фильтром можно запретить вывод этого `acf-comment-fields` ?

```
<div id="acf-form-data"></div>
<div class="acf-comment-fields acf-fields -clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * Filter ACF comment HTML.
 *
 * @param string $html Comment HTML.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function my_comment_form_field_comment( $html ) {
    return '';
}

add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'my_comment_form_field_comment', 1000 );
```

Comment: Такой фильтр `return '';` убирает из  блока с ` id='commentform' `  <p class="comment-form-comment"> в котором находиться `<textarea>`

Comment: А это плохо, поскольку больше ни кто оставить комментарий не сможет

Comment: Так вы напишите конкретно, что вам нужно убрать. И я сделаю. Это простейший preg_replace внутри фильтра. В вопросе пока что сказано убрать весь div acf-comment-fileds.

Comment: Всё верно. Из выдачи необходимо убрать два блока которые добавляете ACF.  `<div id="acf-form-data">` и `<div class="acf-comment-fields">`  , а предложенный фильтр вместе с этим удаляет из выдачи и  `<div id="commentform" >`  с формой комментирования.

Comment: Я не вижу у вас на картинке `<div id="commentform">`

Comment: Это блок который находиться в <div class="comment-form-comment"> заменил изображение если так будет понятнее. Фильтр его тоже убирает